# How to sending emails automatically to Job Applicant immediately after applying, odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I have a cron job and email template and I am trying to write a python code to send acknowledgement emails to new applicants once the application is submitted by applicants and hit the first stage of Recruitment in Odoo 14.
How can I access the applicant that has just applied and trigger the cron job to send the email to the applicant in minutes?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Here's my code.

**Py.py file:**

```
def job_app_acknowledgments(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.partner_id = self.env["hr.applicant"].search(
            [("job_id", "=", job.id), ("stage_id", "=", job._get_first_stage().id)]
        )
        if rec.partner_id:
            ctx = {}
            ctx['email_to'] = rec.partner_id.email
            # ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.user_id.email
            ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.employee_id.work_email
            ctx['send_email'] = True
            ctx['partner_id'] = rec.partner_id.id
            template = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment_new.job_applicant_acknowledgment')
            template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(
                rec.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
```

**Cron.xml**

```
    <record id="job_applicant_acknowledgment" model="ir.cron">
               <field name="name">Job Applicant Acknowledgment Email</field>
               <field name="model_id" ref="hr_recruitment.model_hr_applicant"/>
               <field name="state">code</field>
               <field name="code">model.job_app_acknowledgments()</field>
               <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
               <field name='interval_number'>1</field>
               <field name='interval_type'>minutes</field>
               <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
               <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
            </record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
email_sent is a boolean field.
The cron job is fine then add your email template.

```
def job_app_acknowledgments(self):
    for rec in self:        
        if rec.partner_id and not email_sent:
            ctx = {}
            ctx['email_to'] = rec.partner_id.email
            # ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.user_id.email
            ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.employee_id.work_email
            ctx['send_email'] = True
            ctx['partner_id'] = rec.partner_id.id
            template = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment_new.job_applicant_acknowledgment')
            template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(
                rec.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
```